# Remotely control Android smartphone from Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, android, xfce, remote

Please tell me if and how it‘s possible to remotely control an Honor 7S Android smartphone (it‘s probably a Huawei trademark) with Android version 8.1.0 from 32 bit Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (with xubuntu-desktop/Xfce 4.12) without rooting my phone.

I tried TeamViewer. Here's the details:

On the phone I installed TeamViewer Host version 15.6.51 from the Play Store, the app said remote control is supported on my device and I‘ve been asked to install the Add-On: Huawei (b). I installed it (version 12.1.7267). On the Ubuntu PC I installed TeamViewer version 15.6.7 (for Ubuntu 32-bit from a .deb file). I ran TeamViewer on the Ubuntu PC and signed up to a TeamViewer account. I ran TeamViewer Host on the phone. It asked me to log in to my account. When I pressed the log-in button a message said I have to add my phone as a trusted device and I'd be sent an email with a link. I clicked that link and got a message that my device was added as a trusted device. When I pressed the log-in button again, I was logged in. The app displays a green point and **Ready to connect (secure connection)**. It says to connect to this device I should open https://login.teamviewer.com on my computer, log in with my TeamViewer account and choose this device and cklick "Connect" at "Computer & Contacts". When I open that website and log in I see my device. When I click **Connect** the following message is displayed:

Connect to *number*

Please download TeamViewer full version and install it for experiencing the best possible performance!

**TeamViewer** button

**WebConnector** button

**Chrome App** button (inactive)

Checkbox **Save this selection**

**Cancel**

**Connect** (at first inactive)

When I select **TeamViewer** and click **Connect** (now active) the message **Connect to *number*** is displayed and nothing happens!

When I try to establish the connection directly from TeamViewer instead of the browser, click **Computer & Contacts** and log in, my device is displayed at **My computers** and the status bar says **Ready to connect (secure connection)**. When I doubleclick my device **Connect to partner**, **Connect**, **Authentication**, **Authentication accepted** and **Ready to connect (secure connection)** again is displayed. On the phone it says **Ready to connect (secure connection)**, **Incoming connection**, **Wait for authentication**, **Connected to *My Name*** and **Ready to connect (secure connection)** again. After some time my phone disappears from **My computers** and shows up in **Offline**.

I don't know how to connect and TeamViewer doesn‘t mirror the Android screen!

Comment: what do you mean by remotely control? mirror the screen etc? then use scrcpy, it works over USB and also wireless I think.

Comment: @ashvatthama: I should be able to operate it as if I held it in my hands and perform most of the actions that are possible on a smartphone. The Android screen should be displayed on the Ubuntu PC. As the phone is connected to my WiFi network I'd like to connect to it directly over WiFi or over the internet. My Ubuntu PC is connected to the WiFi router with a LAN cable.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend scrcpy (screen-copy). It allows you to remotely control an Android phone.

First install `scrcpy` and `adb`. `scrcpy` has an Ubuntu package for 20.04, but since you're on 16.04 you can use the Snap package: https://snapstats.org/snaps/scrcpy. `adb` can be installed using `sudo apt install android-tools-adb`.

Here's how to use it with WiFi:

(from https://www.genymotion.com/blog/open-source-project-scrcpy-now-works-wirelessly/)

Here are the steps:

1. Connect the device to the same Wi-Fi as your computer
2. Connect your phone over USB (don't worry, this is temporary, you can unplug later)
3. Get your device IP address (in Settings → About phone → Status)
4. Enable adb over TCP/IP on your device: `adb tcpip 5555`
5. Connect to your device: `adb connect DEVICE_IP:5555` (replace `DEVICE_IP`)
6. Unplug your device from USB
7. Run `scrcpy`

Done. you can change the bandwidth if you want if performance isn't good on your WiFi.

Note: remote sound from android to PC needs at least Android 10. see https://github.com/rom1v/sndcpy.

Comment: Thank you very much! Are the steps 4. and 5. terminal commands that change my phone's settings? I didn't get it right what needs to be replaced in step 5. Could you please explain that a little more? How do I undo the changes to my phone's settings in case that I don't need the remote control any more?

Comment: @user773232 no, it just starts the adb server on your phone to accept connections (it will only allow PCs which you have authorized by saying "Allow USB debugging" to connect). it doesn't change any permanent settings, there's nothing to reverse. As for "I didn't get it right what needs to be replaced": replace "DEVICE_IP" in the command with the device IP you obtained in Step 3.

Comment: Do I type the steps 4. and 5. in a terminal? When you say no permanent settings are changed, does this mean that I need to do to the steps above each time I want to establish a connection? If I only need to do it once, there must be changes that are saved. How would I undo the changes? Something important came to my mind: In step 1 you posted "Connect the device to the same Wi-Fi as your computer". My computer ITSELF DOES NOT HAVE A WI-FI FEATURE/INTERFACE. It's connected to the Wi-Fi router with a cable. Does it work anyway or makes that the whole solution obsolete?

Comment: "Do I type the steps 4. and 5. in a terminal?" - Yes. "When you say no permanent settings are changed, does this mean that I need to do to the steps above each time I want to establish a connection?" - I think each time the device is restarted. "It's connected to the Wi-Fi router with a cable." - That's fine, it's the same network.

Comment: Is it possible to give the Ubuntu PC permanent access to the phone so that I don't have to do all the steps each time I restart the phone? Even though I actually don't want to make permanent changes to my phone's settings I'd accept that for as long as I can completely undo the changes and bring the device back to it's original condition.

Comment: @user773232 Sorry, `adb tcpip 5555` has to be run each time you restart the device. There is an alternative which doesn't need any setup, an app called Vysor, but its wireless feature costs a $2.5/month subscription.

Comment: I've never heard of that app before but I'm admittedly not familiar with the remote control issue. What about connecting over the internet instead of a direct Wi-Fi connection? Is there a way to do it?

Comment: @user773232 I don't know, sorry. I expect that would be quite slow compared to USB/WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Vysor (https://www.vysor.io/). The free version gives an easy way to connect and control your smartphone/tab with your PC's mouse and keyboard. The only issue I found is the inability to view the cursor position on the phone.

The snap could be found in their github releases:
https://github.com/koush/vysor.io/releases

and can be installed locally via:

```
$ snap install <path to snap file> --dangerous #--dangerous flag to avoid signature verification error
```

Check the instructions here:
https://github.com/koush/vysor.io/issues/242